# Modifying HTML strings in C#?

Tags: c#, html

In my MVC solution, I have an HTML string and want to search for comment nodes and replace them based on their content.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

EDIT: The language is C#.  The HTML string is e.g. `"<div id='id1'>blahblah</div><!-- comment1 count='10' length='200' --><p>show real comment content before this paragraph.</p>"`.  I need to get the comment block and then generate real content based on the count and length attributes.

Comment: What is "search comment nodes" and what is "do replacement?"  As it stands, your question is almost equivalent to "hey I want to do something" -- it lacks useful information required to help us help you.

Comment: Please post some more information Jason. What language are you performing the parsing in? Javascript?

Comment: Sorry for the not-clear post. For now what I do is to treat it as regular string and search "<!--". I dunno if there is better and safer way to do search.

Comment: Are you trying to do a template engine ?

Comment: This sounds like something you can do with a regex find and replace in visual studio.

Comment: @HoLyVieR: I think yes, this is what I want. I was thinking maybe I could borrow someting from XmlDocument to search particular node and replace content. If we already have one somewhere on internet, that would be the best ;)

Comment: @JasonLi You can take a look at these question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518954/c-template-engine OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733378/whats-a-good-way-of-doing-string-templating-in-net That should be a good start for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the complexity of HTML you should really use a rich library to help you.

I highly recommend [HTMLAgility](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), you could then follow the advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2363889/148998) to work towards achieving your goal.