# How to strip comments from HTML using Agility Pack without losing DOCTYPE

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am trying to remove unnecessary content from HTML. Specifically I want to remove comments. I found a pretty good solution ([Grabbing meta-tags and comments using HTML Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354653/grabbing-meta-tags-and-comments-using-html-agility-pack)) however the DOCTYPE is treated as a comment and therefore removed along with the comments. How can I improve the code below to make sure the DOCTYPE is preserved?

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment()");
if (nodes != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode comment in nodes)
    {
        comment.ParentNode.RemoveChild(comment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check that comment does not start with `DOCTYPE`

```
  foreach (var comment in nodes)
  {
     if (!comment.InnerText.StartsWith("DOCTYPE"))
         comment.ParentNode.RemoveChild(comment);
  }
```

Comment: Is that safe? What if there is a comment like <!--DOCTYPE blablabla -->? I know it's an edge case but I guess my point is: isn't there a better way than to check the content of the comment node?

Comment: Maybe ignore it when it starts with DOCTYPE and is the FIRST child of the root element?

Comment: I did some testing and figured out the content of the comment actually includes '<!'. This means I can improve your suggestion a little bit: `code`if (!comment.InnerText.StartsWith("<!DOCTYPE"))`code` I still whish there was a better solution than comparing the content of the comment with a hard-coded string...

Answer (score 25):

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
 .Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeType.Comment)
 .ToList()
 .ForEach(n => n.Remove());
```

this will strip off all comments from the document

Comment: This seems the better solution.