# How to strip <!-- --> from given string c# via regex

Tags: c#, regex

How can I remove all string like below

```
<!-- ebanking log on -->
```

second example

```
<!-- 

end the bottom row with 'peace of mind garuntee' 

-->
```

Example document : http://pastebin.com/Y4gZdceK

So it should remove all of the string blocks which starts with `<!--` and ends with `-->`

I tried `htmlagilitypack` inner text but it did not remove

Comment: Your all strings are like `<!-- string1 -->` , `<!-- string2 -->` etc. ??

Comment: `<!--(?!\[).*?(?!<\])-->`  ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/462604

Comment: @NullPointer it failed :(                 regex = new Regex(@"<!--(?!\[).*?(?!<\])-->");
                regex.Replace(srBody, "");

Comment: you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/6567484/390819

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
<!--.*?-->
```

Please note: You have to use `RegexOptions.SingleLine` to change the meaning of the dot (`.`) so it matches every character (instead of every character except `\n`).

Edit: code sample

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"<!--.*?-->", RegexOptions.Singleline);
string strTargetString = @"[sample text here]";

string replacedText = myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, "");
```

Comment: thanks i tried but it failed. also there are code blocks like my second example at updated first post                  regex = new Regex(@"<!--.*?-->", RegexOptions.Singleline);
                regex.Replace(srBody, "");

Comment: I tested it in Regex Hero (http://regexhero.net/tester/) and it works fine for me. It's important that you use the option `RegexOptions.SingleLine`, it makes all the difference.

Comment: No prob, I'm glad I could help :)