# Selenium Execution On Manual Chrome Instances?

Tags: c#, html, google-chrome, selenium, dom

I would like for Selenium code to execute on all instances of chrome, such as having chrome already open, and then running the selenium test, or, manually launching another instance of chrome and selenium automatically run on it as well, is selenium capable of editing elements of a browser that selenium didn't launch?
Or is it only able to modify the browser instance that it launched itself?

My goal is make a application that can customize a users browsing experience by simply running the application and selecting options, and seeing results without refreshing the page.

I have looked into the htmlagilitypack, and read [This Post About xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354653/grabbing-meta-tags-and-comments-using-html-agility-pack/2363889#2363889) however i dont think this can be applied directly to chrome, i have heard something i didnt understand about accessing DOM and running javascript, and i have even been told to try packet injection, however that is unnecessary and would not work on many websites. I have read some of and still reading the documentation. Much of what i find on google gives me mixed answers and end up giving me more questions than answers

Comment: Selenium can't control browser instance not started by itself.

Comment: Veey Well, i need to grab the MD5 hash of chrome.exe however i can probably get around this with a little extra code in the launcher instead of having selenium get it for me. Thank you for your answer.